# tmux: Find all sessions that only have dead panes

Tags: tmux, process-management

I want to find the sessions which only have dead panes, to then kill them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can list all panes and then filter by dead panes:

```
tmux list-panes -a -F "#{pane_dead} #{pane_id}" | grep "^1"
```

And you can kill them with

```
tmux kill-pane -t PANE_ID
```

combine this into:

```
tmux list-panes -a -F "#{pane_dead} #{pane_id}" | \
  awk '/^1/ { print $2 }' | xargs -l tmux kill-pane -t
```